# Copy website tool and IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am copying my website from my local Visual Studio to IIS on a webserver. The files copy fine, but when I open IIS, the folder I copied appears under my website, but also under Default Web Site. The folders are not in two places on the drive (both folders point to the same location) but they are listed twice in IIS. Why is this happening?

- WEB SERVER

  - Application Pools
  - Sites
  - Default Web Site

    - **Account**
    - MyWebSite

      - **Account**

Answer (score 0):

can you check if you have folder on this location as well : C:\inetpub\wwwroot . this is the default website home directory for IIS .

Comment: That was the first thing I checked. No, the folder is only in one physical location. For either folder in IIS, if I right click on the folder and select explore, it takes me to the same place.